# Handle tap event by subview of UIScrollView while scrolling

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I have custom UIScrollView subclass with some content views inside. In some of them I have UITapGestureRecogniser. All works fine when scroll view is not scrolling. But when it scrolling content views does not receive tap action. What is the simplest solution to handle tap action by subview while scroll view is scrolling?

**Details:**

`MyScrollView` scrolls horizontally. It contains a lot of content views (e.g. `MyContentView`). Each `MyContentView` has width about one third of `MyScrollView` width. So there are about 3-4 visible `MyContentView` elements at a moment. The main behavior of `MyScrollView` is to 1)make sure that after scrolling one of `MyContentView` elements will be at center of screen and **2)to scroll to center of `MyContentView` if user taps on it**. So the main answer I hope to get is how to "properly" implement handling of tap action in `MyContentView` while `MyScrollView` is decelerating.

I found some same questions and answers but none of them satisfied me. The best was to implement `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:` of UITapGestureRecogniser delegate. But in this case I sometimes (when I tap, make smaaaal drag and release finger so tap is steel recognizable(lets called it *quasi tap*)) have both tap and scroll events and it leads to bugs for me even if scroll view is not scrolling when I begin tap. When user make *quasi tap* my application tries to scroll to tapped `MyContentView` element and than immediately handle normal scrolling. It seems even more terrible, due to some other functionality start to perform after handling tap (it must not perform when normal scrolling).

I need solution where scroll view wait enough to decide it is not tap event and only then make scroll. Otherwise if tap event had recognized scroll must not happen.

Comment: Can you be more specific in the bugs it's leading you to? Please describe expected results and observed results so we can figure out why it's misbehaving.

Comment: I've edited me question as you ask.

Comment: **shortly, there is no way.** your subviews of the `UIScrollView` cannot receive any interaction from the user until the `UIScrollView` does significant changes in its own position. after the moving is finished the `UIScrollView` passes the tap events to its own subviews and then you can catch them. please, find more information **[here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html)**

Answer (score 5):

You can go with the custom delegates methods as well, using **@protocol**. Implement those delegate methods in view controller where your UIScrollView has been added.

like in **MyContentView**:

In touchesBegan method,

```
[self.delegate contentViewTapped:self];
```

Now in **ContainerView** class where scroll view is added, implement that method:

```
 - (void)contentViewTapped:(MyContentView *)myContentView {

NSLog (@"ContentView no: %d", myContentView.tag); // if tag has been set while adding this view to scrollview.
}
```

Go through the examples for **@protocol**.

Hope this is what you required.

Enjoy Coding :)

Comment: "In touchesBegan method"? It seams that in this case I will just get event every time I put finger down. But I need to handle only "real" tap event.

Comment: no it will not affect your scrollview scrolling event if you are worrying about that then.. I have already done such thing in one of my project.

Comment: @mrunal Even I am looking to implement something similar. My ScrollView perform as MainContainerView which contains multiple Views.Now i am facing issue of Dragging the UIView to particular location within ScrollView.Any how I have implemented this, but still I can't find the position where I have placed it within ScrollView.I have used Pan Gesture for the same.How can I call the touch events from Gestures ?

Answer (score 4):

This is built into `UIScrollView` - take a look at the `delaysContentTouches` and `canCancelContentTouches` properties. This should alleviate the problem when dragging a small bit after a tap.

This is all system built-in behaviour. I would suggest sticking with what Apple has provided for the feel of your interface (how it reacts to small drags, for instance) so that your app doesn't feel out of place on a user's phone.

**EDIT:**

Alternatively, you could disable scrolling of your scroll view in you gesture recognizer and re-enable it once it's ended/cancelled.

**Further Edit:**
I don't understand - I've created a [sample project](http://ashfurrow.com/ScrollViewTest.zip) that illustrates how to intercept touches in a subview of a scroll view using gesture recognizer delegate methods. Play close attention to the "Cancellable Content Touches" and "Delays Content Touches" properties of the scroll view. They're both `YES` for very important reasons.

You scroll view should be delaying content touches until it has determined if the user is attempting a tap, pseudo-tap (as you put it), or a pan for the scroll view. Apple has already written the functionality you're trying to build; `UIScrollView` will already do what you want.

The problem is that the system doesn't want a scroll view's subviews intercepting tap events while the scroll view is scrolling. To this end, it cancels touch events if it determines that the user is actually trying to pan. Setting "Delays Content Touches" enables this behaviour. Ensure it's turned on and you should be fine.

Comment: I've already tried to play with them (and with same properties in UITapGestureRecogniser), but it did not lead to any results at all. It seems that this properties are for low level (with UIEvent and UITouch not UIGestureRecogniser) coding. Or I just can't configurate those properties correctly.

Comment: Those low-level events are used with `UIGestureRecognizer`. Tapping on an element causes a tap gesture recognizer to be cancelled if you move your finger. You should be able to override this behaviour, if you want to, by setting `canCancelContentTouches` to NO, which should disable dragging after the touch of a content view starts tracking.

Comment: I still can't get what I need. Is it possible to implement this behavior without using `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:` method? If possible than how? All fine without it if scroll view is not scrolling. Why I can't receive tap action while scrolling? I'm already so tired of this stuff...

Comment: I've updated my answer again with an explanation of what's going on -`UIScrollView` already has this behaviour as long as it is enabled.

Comment: Thanks for help. But I run your project and it has exact the same problem: it is possible to make tap that causes tap and scroll simultaneously. It is not appropriate for me. I'm trying to find solution where tap and scroll events can't be handled simultaneously. Only scroll or only tap. And tap must recognized while scrolling (without new scroll event).